# A subtle point regarding the axiom of induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, peano-axioms

The fifth of Peano's axioms states the following: If $S\subset \mathbb{N}$  such that $1 \in S$ and $n \in S \Rightarrow \sigma(n) \in S$, then $S = \mathbb{N}$ (where $\sigma(n)$ is the successor function).

My question is, simply, is it of any significance if we alter this to: $S = \mathbb{N}$ if and only if $S\subset \mathbb{N}$  such that $1 \in S$ and $n \in S \Rightarrow \sigma(n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this works. In fact, one might note that, at least as the axioms are listed [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeanosAxioms.html), your statement is equivalent to the conjunction of the 1st, 2nd and 5th axioms which read:

> 1. $1$ is a number.
> 2. If $n$ is a number, then $\sigma(n)$ is a number.

and

> 5. If $S\subset \mathbb N$ is a set, $1\in S$, and $n\in S \Rightarrow \sigma(n)\in S$ then $S=\mathbb N$.

One might notice that the first two axioms are the converse of the fifth - that is, the converse of the fifth is that

> If $S=\mathbb N$, then $1\in S$ and $n\in S\Rightarrow \sigma(n)\in S$ and $S\subset\mathbb N$.

Given that we have both the statement and its converse, we can naturally write:

> $S=\mathbb N$ if and only if $S\subset\mathbb N$, $1\in S$, and $n\in S\Rightarrow\sigma(n)\in S$.

which is precisely the same as the three axioms listed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, sure. After all, starting a sentence with "iff" makes no sense.

**Added**: You are quite correct that the axiom of induction (in that form) is equivalent to $$\bigl(S\subseteq\Bbb N\wedge 1\in S\wedge(n\in S\implies\sigma(n)\bigr)\iff S=\Bbb N.$$

The form given is the less trivial direction of this biconditional.

Comment: That's not a very helpful response. You can just rearrange the sentence, can't you? $S = \mathbb{N}$ if and only if $S\subset \mathbb{N}$  such that $1 \in S$, and $n \in S \Rightarrow \sigma(n) \in S$

Comment: Ah! I see what you're getting at, now.

Comment: How would you go about proving that they are equivalent? Because in the given form it is not a biconditional.

Comment: Since "[statement] and [true statement]" is equivalent to "[statement]," then you need only prove the converse true.